# Edit code via remote gateway with emacs

Tags: emacs, remote-server, gateway

I know that it's possible to edit code on the remote server with emacs and scp. I use tramp for this.
For example it is described here: http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000983.html

But is it possible to edit code via remote gateway with emacs? That means that to access the code one has to login to gateway server first and then login to other server.

Comment: Can you please explain your set-up more precisely? Do you mean ssh rather than scp? The problem probably is not related to emacs, but to your network set-up.

Comment: Em... "scp, or Secure Copy, is a file transfer system based on the SSH".  I don't understand your question... What kind of details of network is important?

Comment: I added a link how to do it with only one server.

Comment: Sorry, I did not recognize from your question that you are working with a *local* instance of emacs. I thought you open an ssh session and work with a remote instance of emacs. With the link you added the problem should be clear, but I do not know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the keyword you are missing is "Multi Hops". It is possible to do this with TRAMP; you'll find all the details in the relevant manual sections :

- [Gateway Methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Gateway-methods)
- [Multi hops](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Multi_002dhops)

For example:

```lisp
;; ensure `tramp-default-proxies-alist' is defined before we append to it
(require 'tramp)

;; Add the proxy rule
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
             '("server2\\.blabla\\.de" nil "/ssh:server1.blabla.de:"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks relevant. But I can't make it work. Suppose I need to do "ssh server1.blabla.de" and "ssh server2.blabla.de" in order to access the files with terminal. How can I do it with emacs? I tried to add (add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
                        '("\\." nil "/scp:server1.blabla.de:"))
           (add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
                        '("\\.blabla\\.de\\'" nil nil)) in .emacs. And type /server2.blabla.de:/ in emacs, this results in "Openning connection for username@server2.blabla.de, which last forever...

Comment: Try using `ssh` as the method, and putting only the first rule: `(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist '("\\." nil "/ssh:server1.blabla.de:"))`

Comment: result is the same. Even if I use /ssh:server2.blabla.de:/ in emacs as well.

Comment: OK, then try to be more explicit in your rule; TRAMP might be stuck in a loop trying to use the proxy to access the reach the proxy itself. See for example my edit.

Comment: Done. And how to use it? /ssh::/ and /server2.blabla.de in emacs results in "no match"

Comment: Something like `/ssh:user@server2.blabla.de:/path/to/the/remote/file`